# Can't drop procedure if object_id is not null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a weird problem. I'm trying to drop a procedure only if it exists, and have this code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.CreateBlogUser', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE CreateBlogUser;
    PRINT 'IS NOT NULL'
GO
```

(the print is only there to try if it is true or not).
And when I run it, "IS NOT NULL" is printed, but the procedure isn't dropped! It still exists in the database, so when I run my Create procedure, it fails.

However! When I tried to remove the NOT from the code, it works! The procedure is dropped and "IS NOT NULL" is still printed. This seems totally backwards and I don't know why it does this. Is is something to do with the extra N:s and U:s in the OBJECT_ID? Found the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace 'U' on 'P'

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.CreateBlogUser', N'P') IS NOT NULL
  DROP PROCEDURE CreateBlogUser;
PRINT 'IS NOT NULL'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer. I didn't know what the letters represented, and that was also why the same code didn't work for my DROP TRIGGER later on, had to replace it with "TR".

Comment: @squ Note.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324(v=sql.105).aspx In section type represented letters each user-defined objects that is created within a database.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL you can try this:-

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'CreateBlogUser')
    exec('CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateBlogUser] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; END')
    PRINT 'IS NOT NULL'
 GO
```

In TSQL you can try this:-

```
 IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.CreateBlogUser', N'P') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.CreateBlogUser;
  PRINT 'IS NOT NULL'
 GO
```

Refer this for [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx)

Comment: Or use the more appropriate and more focused `sys.procedures` system catalog view (instead of `sys.objects` and having to specify a `type=....` parameter)